# Java Bean Validation. Different max size of name for different classes

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation

I use Java Bean Validation in my project. See: https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation

NamedEnitity is my @MappedSuperclass that provides field **name**.

```
@Setter
@Getter
@MappedSuperclass
public class NamedEntity {

    private static final int MAX_LENGTH = 120;

    @NotBlank(message = "Name cannot be empty.")
    @Size(message = "Name cannot be longer then " + MAX_LENGTH + " characters.", max = MAX_LENGTH)
    private String name;

}
```

I have several classes that extended NamedEntity class.
For example **User** entity class.

```
@Setter
@Getter
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User extends NamedEntity {

    // user attributes
}
```

and **Task** entity class

```
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "tasks")
public class Task extends NamedEntity {

    // tasks attributes
}
```

Currently all this classes has **name** field that cannot be longer than 120 characters because of @Size annotation in parent class. But I would like to have different restrictions for different classes. For example I want to restrict name of user to 20 characters and name of task to 150 characters. Moreover I use project Lombok in my application, so I would rather not create any additional getter or setter method. Can you please help me solve this problem?

Comment: Just use two annotations @Size, @Size(value = 20) for User class and @Size(value = 150) for Task class, and remove that annotation from parent class

Comment: Inheritance makes no sense in  these cases. Use inheritance for "is-a" relations, not for "has-a" ones.